# What would human society be like if we could clearly remember our time in the womb?

Tags: society, humans, memory

The Humans of planet Eros in my worldbuilding project have superior memory compared to real humans. This superior memory is advanced enough to allow Erosi Humans to naturally and clearly remember their time in the womb and forward.

Since Erosi Human society is similar to real human society I'm wondering how human society would develop if human memory was advanced enough for humans to naturally remembered their time in the womb, birth, and earliest years. Would this affect our daily skills, behavior, etc?

Comment: VTC:NMF. This is really broad and very opinion-based. How would you choose a best answer? Can you list a series of requirements that define a best answer? Are you asking if (a) a clear memory of the first 5 years of life would change anything or (b) if the ability to remember *exactly* what happened without any of the filters humans have for a reason would change anything? How do we limit the scope of our answer? Do you want to know how many more psychologists would graduate? Whether there'd be more serial killers? How it would affect romance? Whole volumes could be written about this.

Comment: I have met people who swear they can clearly remember events, music they heard, in their mother's womb.

Comment: that's nothing some people can remember their past life ;D

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I once had a discussion with a person who claimed they could remember being sexually attracted to the same sex at age 2 - despite human sexuality not developing until much, much later. I'm honest enough with myself to know that some of my earliest memories - perhaps all of them - are severely tainted by my perception of my own past. In other words, it's easy for people to invent false memories and remarkably difficult to disprove them. Maybe this is my primary concern with this question. It ignores too much of what memory and memory processes really are.

Answer (score 1):

In our society, assuming what they say is true, we have people who can barely remember their life as a teenager, people who can remember things from when they were very young (at times before 4 years old) and some who seem to remember a few things from before leaving the uterus. Do we see any noticeable differences between these people? Yes, the fact that one remembers more about his/her life than the others. If anything, I'm pretty sure we'd only observe slight changes regarding how unborn children are treated in their society, such as more people playing music and talking to their unborn kids and less people saying babies aren't alive until they are born.

The reason I believe that it wouldn't cause any major impacts on daily skills, behavior, etc, is because humans traded almost every other potential weapon nature gave them (except our hands and arms, which are incredibly useful tools) for brains. Our Jaws got weaker and smaller, our heads became bigger, we took a more upright position and we started being born earlier so that our big heads were able to squeeze through the only only available passage for us into into the world at the time. That's one of the reasons why human babies are essentially useless and completely defenseless when compared to other animals, so most of what you'd remember would be staying on a point, looking at stuff, feeling some kind of discomfort, crying and other things children do until they become mobile. One *potential* change could be that, if you can remember in detail such useless information, maybe you can also remember more useful things in detail, so maybe a society with easier time overall remembering stuff. That will come at a cost however, as brains have limited storage, and once it starts to open up space for new information, your memories as a baby mostly incapable of anything that requires a larger use of skeletal muscles will likely be the first to go.